# Can you find my .asmx?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, asmx

A web server running a ASP.NET web service. To use the web service you must go to http://example.com/UtilServerComp/getCashNow7899.asmx

Adding ?WSDL is possible to get service description.

I assume that without knowledge of the URL and exact name of the .asmx this page will not be found or am I wrong? Crawling the web site will not work since you have to guess the name getCashNow7899 as well as UtilServerComp and that is not very likely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather unlikely that someone will find out your service without knowing the name. 
Also remember that you can switch off the documentation protocol:

```
<webServices>
   <protocols>       
       <remove name="Documentation"/>
   </protocols>   
</webServices>
```

However, if you deploy any application that uses the service, the client could use an http debugger to sniff the traffic and learn the exact address and the exposed interface.

Comment: @user1298720 It's basic, but deserves mentioning, to also ensure you have Directory Browsing disabled on the IIS host.

Answer (score 0):

[Why it's a bad idea to rely simply on having a service hidden.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)